# R split a time interval to multiple periods

Tags: r, time, split, intervals, period

Is there a way to split a time interval, say "2018-01-01" to "2019-01-01", to multiple periods/dates?

```
if breaks = "1 month" then it's c("2018-01-01","2018-02-01", ... )
if breaks = "1 quarter" then it's c("2018-01-01","2018-04-01", ... )
if breaks = "1 half yearly" then it's c("2018-01-01","2018-07-01", ... )
if breaks = "1 year" then it's c("2018-01-01","2019-01-01")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Base-R `seq` on a date to get sequences of dates

```
from <- as.Date( "2018-01-01" )
to   <- as.Date( "2019-01-01" )                

seq( from, to, by = "1 month")
# [1] "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-06-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-08-01" "2018-09-01" "2018-10-01"
# [11] "2018-11-01" "2018-12-01" "2019-01-01"

seq( from, to, by = "1 quarter")
#[1] "2018-01-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-07-01" "2018-10-01" "2019-01-01"

seq( from, to, by = "6 month")
#[1] "2018-01-01" "2018-07-01" "2019-01-01"

seq( from, to, by = "1 year")
# [1] "2018-01-01" "2019-01-01"
```